# How to customize tableview header according to my requirement?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, expandable-table

I am trying to implement one feature:

[image]

Image 1 show headers with titles. When you click on header 1,2,3,4 it will expand and shows tableview rows like shown in image 2.

What I want is that at header 0 view, I want to customize and wants to add an image and some text (see image 3).

How to achieve this feature, how can I can I customize tableview header using Objective-C?

I used below code but not showing any changes,

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 18)];
    /* Create custom view to display section header... */
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, tableView.frame.size.width, 18)];
    [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
     NSString *string =[list objectAtIndex:section];
    /* Section header is in 0th index... */
    [label setText:string];
    [view addSubview:label];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:166/255.0 green:177/255.0 blue:186/255.0 alpha:1.0]]; //your background color...
    return view;
}
```

[Here is my project sample](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_NIvryJIblz56tnZcarsmh7ojwmDpedu)

Comment: Do same as cell

Comment: Image 2 is created by me, I want to create a header view. Rest thing is done, only that one part is left.

Comment: See this link, http://www.iostute.com/2015/04/expandable-and-collapsable-tableview.html. Here in this viewForHeaderInSection: function they implemented some views and superator line like this you also do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

user the `viewForHeaderInSection` method . It returns a UIView. You could create your desired UIView() programatically. I assume you know how to do that.

Now, in this method check the `indexPath.row`. IF its "0" then your ImageView Should return ...else return some other view such as a label with a certain text. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Zahurazful can you please check my project code which is I updated now.

Comment: @S Shekh...i cant seem to download it..Dont know why :( Could you post a picture of your edits in code ?

Comment: that link is working fine, anyone can view and download it. If you are not able to download then can you please share me your email id, I will mail you quickly.